# How to query "Followed Count" for each user?

Tags: jquery, rest

I found follow this REST API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194080.aspx#bk_FollowedCount

By using `My/followedcount`, I can get current user's count of items he or she currently following. It is exactly what I need. But I need to list out all users' "Followed Count". How can I do it?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an operation to do it for all users, so you would have to make the calls individually